# Skip a particular test with Travis and run it locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a problem with a test failing on travis because of a timeout error with selenium. This is really frustrating but I'm to the point where bypassing it is an option. This test fails on Travis but passes locally. Is there a way I can have travis skip a particular test and run it on my local machine instead of the CI server? This would be awesome if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the test in an 'if' case testing if the `TRAVIS` variable is set. When you run local this will generally not be set, but it is set by Travis CI:

```
if not ENV['TRAVIS']
    def test_that_fails_on_travis()
        # test something
    end
end
```